# What is the form of the text string in machine code?

Tags: c, assembly, opcode

If I write the following line:

```
char msg[]="Hello";
```

Then I got a hex or binary file for the machine code, what is the form of the word Hello in the machine code file?

Comment: [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/x8vaaz) may give you some hints.

Comment: It depends on where you define it, the compiler, and the architecture. But such an array of characters is read/write. If defined in a function most C compilers build the string on the stack when the function is called. If it is at global scope it will be in a read/write area of memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I searched for it by converting ASCII to hex, but I didn't find anything ?!

Comment: The binary is just going to contain the characters `Hello` followed by a NUL byte.  The exact encoding depends on the character set in use.

Comment: 0x48,0x65,0x6C,0x6C,0x6F,0x00

Answer (score 3):

Program files consist of program code in machine code language, and program data as binary data.

Strings, arrays, pointers, ints, and floats are examples of data — as such, they go in the binary for the executable program file, but they are not machine code.  Only program code translates into machine code.

So, there is not really a such thing as "machine code" for data — instead there are standard for the representation of data, such as C-style null terminated strings, ASCII codes for characters, UTF-8 for international strings, 2's complement integers, IEEE 754 for floating point representations, and language specific things for booleans, enums, etc..

Comment: If `char msg[]="Hello";` was a local variable (automatic storage), GCC for x86 would emit a couple mov stores with immediate operands to store the data to the stack, embedding the data into machine code.  But the OP's level of understanding is not clear, and that's probably not what they were asking about.

Comment: Yes, but the char [] itself would materialize as runtime data.  Hope that helps the OP.

Comment: Yes, of course.  But the answer to the literal question "*what is the form of the word Hello in the machine code **file**?*" would be "as 4-byte or 8-byte immediates for `mov` instructions", for that case.  I'm pretty sure there's a disconnect between what the OP really wants / needs to know / understand vs. what they're asking, so I upvoted your answer because it seems like a good attempt at the basics.

Comment: Only under the conditions that it is a local variable, though, of course.  Global data and string literals would not manifest as immediates in instructions.  And a sufficiently large local char [] would probably involve a copy from data rather than machine code language immediates.

Comment: yep, was definitely only talking about my specific hypothetical example with that short string.  I added a "for that case" to my previous comment to make that crystal clear.  Your answer seems to exclude that case, which is probably fine as an oversimplification, but that's why I brought it up.

Comment: Yes, good discussion, hope it helps the OP.  A .word or dc.w or dc.q declaration if we take the question so literally is data declaration as per above answer.